# Custom command won't run at startup

Tags: release-loki, startup

I need to remap the Capslock key of my keyboard to backspace.

I use the command:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:backspace & xset r 66
```

which works perfectly when run from the terminal. But if I set it to run at startup as a custom command trough `System setings/Aplications/Startup` (translated from Spanish), it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you put your answer as an answer and not as en edit of your question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are actually two commands, you might want to create a startup script `~/.local/bin/remap_capslock` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -option caps:backspace &
xset r 66
```

set it to executable

```
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/remap_capslock
```

and run this script at startup

Comment: I would suggest using `~/.local/bin` instead of `~/bin` for several reasons: It already exists, it's hidden, and it's on the path.

Comment: It must be relatively a new thing, I always used `~/bin` thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I just put it in my home folder.

Answer (score 1):

After making this question I realized that elementary OS can do this via settings, with no need to mess with configuration files. Just go to `System settings/Keyboard/Layout` and select your desired `Capslock` behaviour.

[image]

The bad news is that it doesn't work if you keep the key pressed (as the `Backspace` key does)